# To delete the blank tr in html

Tags: c#, html

I am having a default template in my project. Items like Name, City and Country are replaced with the User data.

Sometimes the data is replaced with the null data which leaves the row blank. I want to delete that particular empty row

My html template is below:

```
<tr>
 <td>City</td>
 <td>&nbsp;</td>
 <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
```

this is my html template. If the City is replaced with null then I want to delete the entire row.

I want delete the rows for the data which are replaced with null value

Since we are fetching the template from 3rd party, Jquery is the last option am looking for. Is there any other way to resolve this?

Any help would be highly appreciated

I need to parse a html template. Part of the Html template looks like below

```
 <table>
    <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <tr>
    <tr>
    <td>City</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Country</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <tr>
    </table>
```

The above template is then replaced with the user data using C#.

```
if (obj.City == null || obj.City == "Specific Parameter")
                        {
                            strGetBody = strGetBody.Replace("City", "");

                        }

                        else
                        {
                            strGetBody = strGetBody.Replace("City", obj.City);

                        }
```

Below is the template after replacing the generic data to user data

```
        <table>
        <tr>
        <td>Abc</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <tr>
        <tr>
        <td>**&nbsp;**</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <tr>
        <tr>
        <td>India</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <tr>
        </table>
```

I want to parse the tr whose value is null. Is there any possible way to parse the tr element and delete the entire row if the td value is null for that row?

Comment: Check for `null` values before you add a row.

Comment: You mention `jquery` but tagged the question with `c#` and `html`. Please make up your mind. How are you reading the values for the template? Where and how is that template stored? When you say "delete the rows" what do you mean? Where are those "rows" stored?

Comment: @Bharadwaj general table is already present. If the invalid data is entered by user then we are replacing that row data  with null value.

Comment: @Jcl template is stored in cloud storage. We are fetching the template from there. Rows are stored in the template. If the invalid data is entered by the user, we replace it with Null value which results the blank row

Comment: `Cloud storage` doesn't really mean a lot. A Synology? OneDrive? Azure? XML? HTML? JSON? How is the user entering the data? Is this related to `c#` at all (since you tagged it with `c#`)? This question is FAR from clear.

Comment: instead of deleting rows which have `null`, prevent from saving invalid data or prevent user from adding invalid data.

Comment: @Jcl it is stored in Salesforce in a HTML format. we are using C# in order to process the template to the end user

Comment: @Bharadwaj :Input of data is not in our scope. we are just fetching and auditing the data entered by user

Comment: @user3406037 you should really learn to ask good questions. This one is not. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) link to the FAQ, and this excellent post by Jon Skeet on [writing good questions](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Basically, with the question you provided, there is **no way** one can give a good answer. Too many things to guess. Even `null` doesn't mean the same or is treated equal depending on the context, and you are giving zero context (at least, related to programming).

Comment: Can't block while auditing?

Comment: @Bharadwaj yes if the entered data is not valid, we keep a policy to replace with the blank value.

Comment: @Bharadwaj Can we parse the particular tr using XML parser?

Comment: The answer to the question should be `check for any nulls and just don't write the template out when there is any`... how you do that is what is confusing, since you are not giving a context on HOW you are processing the template and where and how you are writing the output to. C# is not a valid context... "using a razor view on a asp.net application", or "we are using C# to read from a webservice and write to a log file" could be. Some of *your* code could also help

Comment: @Jcl I apologize for creating a confuse state. We deliver the html template to the user end after replacing the generic data with the user data

Comment: I'm trying to get you understand that you are just "exposing what you are doing" but not "how you are doing it". There are 
***infinite*** ways in computing for "delivering the html template to the user". You need to give us a context to work with. Preferably with some code stating what you have tried. **You** know that context but **we** don't, so it's impossible that we can answer your question if we don't even know the technology that you are using for that specific task.

Comment: here i have added my code context.I want to eliminate the tr which contains a blank data in respective <td>

Comment: Ok, now we are starting to talk. Still, it's not clear where `strGetBody` is coming from and where is it going to, but now we have something to work with. I'll write a possible answer

Comment: strGetBody is a string parameter which holds the html template

Answer (score 0):

Taking your latest edit with some code. I assume you are having a function that gets `strGetBody` as a parameter and needs to return the modified output according to some object... if this is the case, why not just not returning anything?

```
private string myFunctionForEachTR(string strGetBody, myObject obj)
{
  if (obj.City == null || obj.City == "Specific Parameter")
    return string.Empty;
  return strGetBody.Replace("City", obj.City);
}
```

## Update

Based on your requirements, rather than parsing the HTML (which, if you find this difficult, parsing HTML might look like extremely hard for you), you could just do this before returning the template:

```
strGetBody = strGetBody.Replace("<tr>\n\r<td>\n\r</td>\n\r<td>&nbsp;</td>\n\r</tr>","");
```

To just remove the whole empty `<tr>` tag. Notice you may have to fiddle with line breaks (might be `\r` only, `\n\r`, or `\r\n`) and maybe the spaces to find out how exactly your template is defined to match it on the `Replace` function.

Comment: yes I have replaced with string.empty. But this results in a blank row which is spoiling the template look and feel. Is there any way to hide or delete the particular tr?

Comment: you could parse the HTML and remove the <tr> but I'd say that's overkill... again, more context is needed: what does `strGetBody` contain **exactly** and how are you looping through your objects to get the result?

Comment: please can you help me how to parse the HTML ?

Comment: I have updated my answer showing a possible way. As I said there, if this is proving difficult to you, parsing HTML should be out of the question (it's not exactly easy to parse HTML).

Comment: Thanks..will try with this reg expression @jcl

Comment: It's not a regular expression, it's a simple plain text replace

Answer (score 0):

I replaced  `<tr>` with `<tr style="display:none">` at required conditions which worked amazingly :)

```
if (obj.City == null || obj.City == "Specific Parameter")
{
  if(strGetBody.Contains("<tr id=\"city\">"))
    {
    strGetBody = strGetBody.Replace("<tr id=\"city\">", "<tr id=\"city\" style=\"display:none\">");
    }
}
else 
{
   strGetBody = strGetBody.Replace("City", obj.City);

}
```

Answer (score -1):

there are two ways.

1. before dropping values in `<tr>` tag check if the value is null and make the `<tr>` attribute hidden.
2. after dropping values use js

   ```
   document.getElementById("xyz").style.visibility="hidden";
   ```